# Redirecting a directory to a page

Tags: html, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

The website is currently on WordPress so the pages are listed as pathways ie www.xyz.com/content/ on Google.  We are in the process of changing to a new HTML site outside of Wordpress.  The new page is www.xyz.com/content.html (plus we removed the html within htaccess.

However, if someone clicks over from Google with the old page reference, they get a 500 internal server error.

It there a way to redirect all directories (pathways) to specific pages like

redirect domain/*/ to domain/* ???

Comment: Sure that is possible. You need to implement rewrite rules from the old to the new URLs.

Comment: What is your current htaccess file?

Answer (score 0):

By default, `Redirect` sort of *maps* the path node to a new path node, so anything after the first path gets appended to the target URL.

Try:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/abc/cba/ http://www.example.com/?
```

Or if you'd rather use mod_rewrite instead of mod_alias:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?abc/cba/ http://www.example.com/? [R=301,L]
```